# Guidelines for solving $\int \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)} \:dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I'm aware of $\int \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} \:dx$ as a model solution 
The question that prompted this thought was :
$$\int \frac{x + \sin(x)}{1 + \cos(x)} dx$$  
I do know how to solve it but I find the trigonometric solution a bit ick-y and was wondering if a model, perhaps even a guideline could help me face questions in the format given in the title, better.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Notice that $f'(x)/f(x) = (\log(x))'$.

Comment: @user57 The OP is asking for $f(x)/f'(x)$. Moreover, you meant $\log|f(x)|$ as antiderivative.

Comment: $(x\ln(x)-x)/(\ln(x))$ doesn't have elementary anti-derivatives.

Comment: I think the title of this question should be $\int \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}\,dx$ instead. Instead of looking for ways to integrate $\int \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}\,dx$, this integral can be split into two and then you will notice that one of the integrals is of the form $\int \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\,dx$.

Comment: Based on the problem you've given, I'd think asking about $\int{\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}dx}$ would be more appropriate?

Comment: Multiply top and bottom by $1-\cos(x)$. Then, use integration by parts

Comment: ayan and bb_823, Yes, the original question had the right form, I think an editor mistook the expression as the other way around.

Answer (score 4):

As Tyma Gaidash suggested,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\quad & \int \frac{(x+\sin x)(1-\cos x)}{1-\cos ^2 x} d x 
\\= & -\int(x+\sin x-x \cos x-\sin x \cos x) d(\cot x) \\
= & -(x+\sin x)(1-\cos x) \cot x+\int \cot x(1+\cos x+x \sin x-\cos x-\cos 2 x) d x \\
= & -(x+\sin x)(1-\cos x) \cot x+  \int \cot x\left(2 \sin ^2 x+x \sin x\right) d x =…
\end{aligned}
$$
Wish it helps.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of $y = \frac{x}{2}$, the integral is
$$2 \int (1 \cdot \tan y + y \cdot \sec^2 y)\,dy = 2 \int (y \tan y)' \,dy = 2 y \tan y + C = x \tan \frac{x}{2} + C. $$